# Print the page loaded by url of object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, reactjs

I am trying to print the contents of reactjs modal. I embedded a url in the modal and want to print the modal with those contents. Below is my code

```
<Modal.Body>
          <div>
             <object id="printableArea" type="text/html" data="http://www.xyztest.net/obj.html" className="objectClass">
        </object>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
```

My print button function is

```
handleToggle: function (divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

This doesn't print the object tag url content.. Pls let me know how this can be achieved.. I dont want to use iframes

Answer (score 0):

A popup might be an easier and more reliable solution to this. Assuming `divName` is referring to the `<object>` tag, you could do something like:

```
handleToggle: function (divName) {
    var url = document.getElementById(divName).getAttribute('data');
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;" src="'+url+'" frameborder=0></iframe');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       win.window.print()
    }, 1000);
}
```

This opens a blank popup window, writes an iframe and sets the src to be your url. It then waits a second for the page to load and triggers printing

Comment: This doesnt work.. already tried it.. its opening the print popup with nothing on it..

Comment: Like I said, you need to ensure that `document.getElementById(divName)` is returning the `<object>` tag, I have no idea what `divName` is. If it is returning the object, it should work

Comment: divName is the id on the object tag.. its returning the css class on the object tag but not the actual html content of the embedded page ..my url is something like this http://example.com/admin.html

Comment: the url is an https url .can that be an issue?

Comment: I am trying to avoid iframes here because its not supported by some browser.. Also if the content in the modal is scrollable then it doesnt print the whole of the content..

Comment: This wasn't requested in the OP, but this doesn't work if the data attribute contains a URL to a PDF.